# Java JPA Hibernate - Error: Infinite recursion

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 3 entities(Product, Providers and Prices) where Prices is linked to the other 2. A product can have multiple prices, one price per provider:
[image]

Product class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products") 
public class Product implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "product_id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "product_category")
private String productCategory;

@Column(name = "product_subcategory")
private String productSubcategory;

@Column(name = "product_name")
private String productName;

@Column(name = "product_description")
private String productDescription;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.product", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Prices_1> prices_1 = new HashSet<Prices_1>(0);


public Set<Prices_1> getPrices_1(){
    return prices_1;
}

public void setPrices_1(Set<Prices_1> prices_1){
    this.prices_1 = prices_1;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getProductCategory() {
    return productCategory;
}

public void setProductCategory(String productCategory) {
    this.productCategory = productCategory;
}

public String getProductSubcategory() {
    return productSubcategory;
}

public void setProductSubcategory(String productSubcategory) {
    this.productSubcategory = productSubcategory;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

public String getProductDescription() {
    return productDescription;
}

public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
    this.productDescription = productDescription;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ProductController [id=" + id + ", productName=" + productName
            + ", productCategory=" + productCategory + ", productSubcategory=" + productSubcategory
            + ", productDescription=" + productDescription
            + "]";
}

}
```

Provider class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="providers")
public class Provider implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="provider_id")
private int id;

@Column(name="provider_name")
private String providerName;

@Column(name="provider_address")
private String providerAddress;

@Column(name="provider_phone")
private String providerPhone;

@Column(name="provider_archived")
private int providerArchived = 0;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.provider")
private Set<Prices_1> prices_1 = new HashSet<Prices_1>(0);

public Set<Prices_1> getPrices_1() {
    return prices_1;
}

public void setPrices_1(Set<Prices_1> prices_1) {
    this.prices_1 = prices_1;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getProviderName() {
    return providerName;
}

public void setProviderName(String providerName) {
    this.providerName = providerName;
}

public String getProviderAddress() {
    return providerAddress;
}

public void setProviderAddress(String providerAddress) {
    this.providerAddress = providerAddress;
}

public String getProviderPhone() {
    return providerPhone;
}

public void setProviderPhone(String providerPhone) {
    this.providerPhone = providerPhone;
}

public int getProviderArchived() {
    return providerArchived;
}

public void setProviderArchived(int providerArchived) {
    this.providerArchived = providerArchived;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ProviderController [id=" + id + ", providerName=" + providerName
            + ", providerAddress=" + providerAddress + ", providerPhone="
            + providerPhone + "]";
}

}
```

Prices_1 class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "prices_1")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.product",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.provider",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id"))})
public class Prices_1 implements java.io.Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private PricesId pk = new PricesId();

@Column(name = "price")
private float price;

public PricesId getPk() {
    return pk;
}

public void setPk(PricesId pk) {
    this.pk = pk;
}

public float getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(float price) {
    this.price = price;
}

@Transient
public Product getProduct() {
    return getPk().getProduct();
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    getPk().setProduct(product);
}

@Transient
public Provider getProvider() {
    return getPk().getProvider();
}

public void setProvider(Provider provider) {
    getPk().setProvider(provider);
}


public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;

    Prices_1 that = (Prices_1) o;

    if (getPk() != null ? !getPk().equals(that.getPk())
            : that.getPk() != null)
        return false;

    return true;
}

public int hashCode() {
    return (getPk() != null ? getPk().hashCode() : 0);
}

}
```

PricesID class:

```
@Embeddable
public class PricesId implements java.io.Serializable {

@ManyToOne
private Product product;

@ManyToOne
private Provider provider;

public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public Provider getProvider() {
    return provider;
}

public void setProvider(Provider provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    PricesId that = (PricesId) o;

    if (product != null ? !product.equals(that.product) : that.product != null) return false;
    if (provider != null ? !provider.equals(that.provider) : that.provider != null) return false;

    return true;
}

public int hashCode() {
    int result;
    result = (product != null ? product.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (provider != null ? provider.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}

}
```

ProductsRepository class:

```
@Repository
public class ProductsRepository {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

public List<Product> findAllProducts(){
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Product e");
    return (List<Product>) query.getResultList();
}

}
```

ProductsService class:

```
@Service
public class ProductsService {

@Autowired
ProductsRepository productsRepository;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Product> findAllProducts(){
    List<Product> pv = productsRepository.findAllProducts();
    return pv;
}

}
```

ProductsController class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("product")
public class ProductController {

@Autowired
private ProductsService productsService;

@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Product> getProducts(){
    List<Product> productList = productsService.findAllProducts();
    for (Product p : productList){
        System.out.println("Andres. Provider name: " + p.getProductName());
    }
    return productList;
}
}
```

ArrayList productlist returned by controller:
[image]

The problem is that Products[0] has 2 Prices_1. Prices_1[0] has associated a Product and a Provider and both has associated a Prices_1, etc. Ending up in a infinite loop

Any ideas how can I get the following object:
List of Products, each product with a list of prices, one price per provider.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
The issue is not with the ArrayList productList created, the error is trigger when that productList object is returned to the browser:

[image]

Comment: How are you returning it to browser ? -It might be because when it is converted to json the toString() method is called which tries to serialize the product and provider defined inside the prices_1. Try to define the product and provider as transient inside the pricesid class.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response @PushpendraPal . I and returning to the browser "return productList;" (the ArrayList productList). I have added "@Transient" to both, Product and Provider objects in PricesId.java but the app does not run: "PricesId has no persistent id property: ....model.Prices_1.pk". The auto-serialisation was my first concern, that is why I override all toString() methods (Producs, Providers and Prices_1).

Comment: hmm... I think overriding toString() on product and providers will not work as when you return the productList the toString() will be invoked on the list (java.util.List of your products). which is not overridden and will still look for serialization of all the objects inside your list....
Also I observed that toString is not overriddern for prices_1.....

Comment: Hi @PushpendraPal, I added "@Override toString()" in Prices_1 class but does not make any difference.

Comment: you can try creating Generic list of your product. The generic i am giving below in the answer.. then return the String from controller by using toString on GenericClass<Product> object...

you can add other unimplemented methods to this GenericClass but no need to provide the implementations for those

Comment: Also create the Generic list like this

GenericClass<Product> list = new GenericClass<>();
list.addAll(productList);
return list.toString();

Comment: Thanks @PushpendraPal, basically what I have done to slve the issue is create a Data Transfer Object: ProductDTO to customise the JPA Product Entity, please see my response below.

Comment: looks good. actually any serialization have problem with bi-directional relationships including Jackson as well. which  is  what  happening  in your  case  too.

Comment: you can actually try another short solution by annotating your method with @JsonManagedReference, which returns your product list.

Comment: @A TORRE,  And annotating your getter getProduct () with @JsonBackReference in many to one relationship in prices_1 class.

Comment: Hi @PushpendraPal, thanks for the comments. I have tried "@JsonManagedReference" but the app errors when returns List<Product> producList: Failed to write HTTP message: --> JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: in addition to "@JsonManagedReference" you also have to specify the getter getProduct () in prices_1 class with "@JsonBackReference."

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GenericClass<E> implements List<E> {

private List<E> list;
public GenericClass() {
    this.list = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (E e : list) {
        s.append(e.toString());
    }
    return s.toString();
}

@Override
public boolean add(E e) {

    return list.add(e);
}

@Override
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {

    return list.addAll(c);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have created 3 Data Tansfer Object to customise and concert the  List productList:

```
public class ProductsDTO {

private List<ProductDTO> productDTOSet = new ArrayList<ProductDTO>(0);

public ProductsDTO(List<ProductDTO> productDTOSet) {
    this.productDTOSet = productDTOSet;
}

public static ProductsDTO mapFromProductSetEntity(List<Product> products){
    List<ProductDTO> productDTOs = new ArrayList<ProductDTO>(0);
    for (Product p : products) {
        productDTOs.add(ProductDTO.mapFromProductEntity(p));
    }
    return new ProductsDTO(productDTOs);
}

public class ProductDTO {

private int id;
private String productCategory;
private String productSubcategory;
private String productName;
private String productDescription;
private Set<PriceDTO> prices = new HashSet<PriceDTO>(0);


public ProductDTO(int id, String productCategory, String productSubcategory, String productName,
                  String productDescription, Set<PriceDTO> prices) {
    this.id = id;
    this.productCategory = productCategory;
    this.productSubcategory = productSubcategory;
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productDescription = productDescription;
    this.prices = prices;
}

public static ProductDTO mapFromProductEntity(Product product){

    Set<PriceDTO> priceDTOs = new HashSet<PriceDTO>(0);
    for (Prices_1 p1 : product.getPrices_1()){
        priceDTOs.add(PriceDTO.mapFromPrice_1Entity(p1));
    }

    return new ProductDTO(product.getId(), product.getProductCategory(), product.getProductSubcategory()
    , product.getProductName(), product.getProductDescription(), priceDTOs);
}
}

public class PricesDTO {

private Set<PriceDTO> pricesDTO = new HashSet<PriceDTO>(0);

public Set<PriceDTO> getPricesDTO() {
    return pricesDTO;
}

public void setPricesDTO(Set<PriceDTO> pricesDTO) {
    this.pricesDTO = pricesDTO;
}
}
```

An then map the List productList to the DTOs:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("product")
public class ProductController {

@Autowired
private ProductsService productsService;

@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ProductsDTO getProducts(){
    List<Product> productList = productsService.findAllProducts();
    for (Product p : productList){
        System.out.println("Andres. Provider name: " + p.getProductName());
    }

    return ProductsDTO.mapFromProductSetEntity(productList);
}
}
```

And this is the result:
[image]